# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'delete') in Discord.js V13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have been getting this error in the **"interactionCreate"** event in my bot, this error causes my bot to shut down every time it occurs.

```sh
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'delete')
at Timeout._onTimeout (/root/Teyrox/GamesMadeInPolaDiscordBot/events/servidores/interactionCreate.js:12:403)
  at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
  at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

The error occurs in this line of code, and after a while of research and checking I did not find any error in this line of code

```js
if (aBoolean) return interaction.reply({ content: `<:x_:677580192641843222>`, ephemeral: true }).then(m => setTimeout(() => m.delete().catch(() => { }), 15000));
```

Comment: This may not necessarily be the cause of your issue, but the entire concept behind your code is flawed. This code will never work, because ephemeral messages cannot be deleted. They are designed to be "deleted" or hidden solely by the user themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched on the internet and found [this](https://githubmemory.com/repo/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/2919) gitmemory forum. I states that:

> ...we can only edit Ephemeral Message but we can't delete Ephemeral Message...

You can't delete Ephemeral messages. They're designed to be dismissed by the recipient of the message